# How do I get a shorter title rule using titlesec?

Tags: titlesec

I am using the titlesec package to format my chapters. I want them to look like this:

[image: Example of how it should look]

Currently, I use the code underneath. However, my titlerule is now textwidth.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\filcenter}
{\normalfont\scshape\Large{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\huge}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead, edit your question to show a compilable document containing the fragments that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\titleline` command to insert your own rule and specify its length:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\filcenter}
{\normalfont\scshape\Large{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titleline[c]{\rule{3.5cm}{.5pt}}
\vspace{1pc}%
\huge}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]